# How to use hugo's front matter variable to sort my taxonomy

Tags: html, css, hugo

I was trying to sort the hugo's categories on taxonomy. 
So I defined a custom front-matter variable 'root', Planning to use the root's value as the first-level directory. And the categories as the subdirectory.

But when I using `.Params.root` to access the variable I can't get the right value, it just returns null. So what's caused this problem? Does it caused by that the taxonomy didn't af specific detailed page or the way of mine to access the variable are wrong?

I know that I can define a data file to achieve the effects I want but I just wanna figured a way to use the front-matter variable.

```html
{{ partial "head.html" . }}
{{ partial "header.html" . }}

{{ $termName := .Data.Plural }}
{{ $terms := .Data.Terms.ByCount }}
{{ $length := len $terms }}
{{ $type := .Type }}
{{ $root := .Params.root}}


<!-- Categories Page -->
<div class="post {{.Data.Plural}}">
   <!--<h2 class="post-title" style="text-align:right;padding-bottom:2em">-&nbsp;{{ .Data.Plural | humanize }}&nbsp;-</h2>
--> 
{{ if and $.Site.Taxonomies.categories (eq $termName "categories") }}

<p>{{ $root }}</p>
<div class="categories-card">
{{ range $terms }}
    {{ $term := .Term }}
    {{ $pages := .Pages }}
    {{ with $.Site.GetPage "taxonomy" (printf "%s/%s" $type $term) }}
         <div class="card-item">
           <div class="categories" >
             <a href="{{ .URL }}"><h3> <i class="fas fa-folder" style="padding-right: 3px"></i> {{  $term | humanize }} </h3> </a>
               {{ range first 5 $pages }}   
                <article class="archive-item">
                <a href="{{ .URL }}" class="archive-item-link">{{ .Title }}</a>
                </article>
              {{ end }}
               {{ if gt (len $pages) 5 }}
                  <span class="more-post">
                    <a href="{{ .Permalink }}" class="more-post-link">More >></a>
               </span> 
               {{ end }}
           </div>
        </div>
    {{ end }}
{{ end }}
</div> <!-- //categories-card -->
 <!-- Tag cloud Page -->
{{ else if and $.Site.Taxonomies.tags (eq $termName "tags") }}
     <div class="tag-cloud-tags">
          {{ range $.Site.Taxonomies.tags.ByCount }}
            {{ if .Name }}
            <a href="/tags/{{ .Name | urlize}}/"> {{ .Name }} <small>({{ .Count }})</small></a>
            {{ end }}
          {{end}}
     </div>
{{ end }}
</div>
</div>



{{ partial "footer.html" . }}
{{ partial "analytics.html" . }}
```

Comment: is 'root' in your config.yaml or in the front matter of your pages?